# NullPointerException in WebappClassLoader

Tags: tomcat, nullpointerexception

I run into the following error in my `catalina.out`

```
mmap failed for CEN and END part of zip file
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.findResourceInternal(WebappClassLoader.java:3059)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.findResource(WebappClassLoader.java:1254)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.getResourceAsStream(WebappClassLoader.java:1504)
```

This does not happen all the time and happened only on a 32bit machine.
Any idea what is causing it?

Comment: Tried on this case with similar error reason?http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12815309/java-outofmemory-exception-mmap-error-on-loading-zip-file

Comment: Does not seem related: /proc/$PID/maps | wc -l  is significantly lower then the limit.